# RoR 2.3.8 Problematic Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been having all kinds of problems with one preexisting table I generated scaffolding for.  The symptoms all seem to be related to the id missing or being misinterpreted.

My table looks like this:

```
                      Table "public.notes"
     Column      |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage  | Description 
-----------------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------
 id              | integer |           | plain    | 
 data            | text    |           | extended |
```

I generated scaffolding like so:

```
script/generate scaffold notes id:integer data:string --skip-migration
```

The first problems I saw cropped up trying to access any route in the /notes path.  Any time there was a link to a specific note, the path would fail to generate.  'Show' links, for example, are defined normally like so:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', note %>
```

Pretty much all routes like this that should just work fail with errors that look like this:

```
edit_note_url failed to generate from {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"notes", :id=>#<Note id: 13, data: "This is a test note.">}, expected: {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"notes"}, diff: {:id=>#<Note id: 13, data: "This is a test note.">}
```

Since this failed to work as expected, but I modified the link like so and things progressed smoothly once again:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', :action => :show, :id => note[:id].to_s %>
```

The problem I've run into now (which is making me realize something deeper is wrong here and working around the problem isn't the answer) is that attempting to edit a note results in no change.  Inspecting the logs reveals the following:

```
  Parameters: {"data"=>"This is a test note being modified.", "commit"=>"Update", "authenticity_token"=>"+ue4O6EimVNyZVHdgChy+/0w07vc5HuxFc/IQZX+rpA=", "id"=>"13"}
  Note Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM "notes" WHERE ("notes"."id" = 13) 
  SQL (0.2ms)   BEGIN
  Note Update (0.3ms)   UPDATE "notes" SET "data" = E'This is a test note being modified.' WHERE "id" = NULL
  SQL (0.2ms)   COMMIT
```

So, I'm clearly doing something wrong here.  Can someone help me out and point out whatever rails convention I've failed to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you link to a resource using its associated resource path, and that's defined in `config/routes.rb` with the Rails 2.3 notation:

```
map.resources :notes
```

This will generate a number of routes that are visible in the output of `rake routes` but the one you're looking for is this:

```
<%= link_to('Show', note_path(note)) %>
```

In order to verify that your Note model is working correctly, you should have some simple unit tests that exercise creating, updating, and reading a note from the test database to be sure you haven't done something wrong inadvertently.

There's something suspicious happening there because in the `UPDATE` statement the `id` attribute has ended up `nil` which means that won't apply properly. Is there anything unusual in your model?

As a note, you should not use `note.id` directly when linking to it through a URL or `_path` call because this may not be how the object is supposed to be addressed. It is common for things to over-ride their `to_param` method to customize this behavior and side-stepping it like that is a recipe for trouble. As a general rule, use `note.id` only in the context of SQL, and `note.to_param`, if you need to, for URL purposes. Generally the URL generator will take care of this for you.

Comment: Like I said, I generated all of the code using scaffold generation code.  The model, the routes, etc, are all generated this way.  map.resources :notes exists in the routes.rb file, and is present in rake routes output:
            note GET    /notes/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"notes"}

Comment: Still wondering what you've done to make your model lose the `id` attribute before saving.